# How to get the unique count of a particular part of a string

Tags: shell, text-processing, scripting, grep, sort

I have a set of data in a file.

```
psf7433-nlhrms
unit7433-nobody
unit7333-opera
bpx7333-operations
app7333-osm
unit7330-partners
psf7331-pdesmond
unit7333-projm
mnp7330-redirect
unit7333-retailbanking
cpq7333-rkarmer
unit6333-sales
ring7323-support
unit7133-telco
post7323-uadb
sun7335-ukhrms
burp7133-wfnmreply
```

How to ignore the starting alphabetic characters in each line and the characters after the numeric and get the count of the unique numbers.
(or)
How to retrieve only the numeric value in each line and get their unique count.

Considering we manage to extract only the numeric values, we will get this.

```
7433
7433
7333
7333
7333
7330
7331
7333
7330
7333
7333
6333
7323
7133
7323
7335
7133
```

Now, I want the unique count of the retrieved numeric values. So ignoring the repetitions, I should get the following final output.

```
8
```

I am unable to do this either by using **awk** or **sed** or even simple **grep | cut**

I do not want the list of extracted values, I want only the final count as the answer.

Help me!

Comment: I only get 8 unique values.

Answer (score 5):

With `grep`, filter out just the numbers:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+-' file | sort -u | wc -l
```

- `[0-9]` Matches any character between 0 and 9 (any digit).
- `+` in [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Fundamental-Structure.html#Fundamental-Structure) stands for at least one character (that's why the `-E` option is used with `grep`). So `[0-9]+-` matches one or more digits, followed by `-`.
- `-o` only prints the part that matched your pattern, so given input `abcd23-gf56`, `grep` will only print `23-`.
- `sort -u` sorts and filters unique entries (due to `-u`), and `wc -l` counts the number of lines in input (hence, the number of unique entries).

Comment: i'm new to shell scripting so can you explain what this script does in short. thanks a ton!

Comment: as per my requirement, the script should ignore any numeric value after the '-' character in the input (if any). For eg: if the input is sun7335-ukhrms8768, it should not read 8768 as it falls after the '-' character.

Comment: @Karthik Does the `-` appear only once per line? And does it always appear after the first number?

Comment: yes only once  .

Comment: @Karthik check the update.

Comment: @mikeserv presence of multiple numbers might be a problem. See the second comment on this answer.

Comment: good point. missed that. plus `echo` was dumb - but if the last line doesn't end in a newline your counts will be off by one.

Comment: @mikeserv I suppose a `{grep ...; echo}` should fix that?

Comment: @muru `grep -Eo '[0-9]+-' file | sort -u | wc -l` gives me an approximate count when applied on my original input file. Thanks. Now, I need a small favor. Let me pull out 5 entries from my input. `unit7433-nobody unit7333-opera unit7333-retailbanking unit7133-telco unit6333-sales`. This type 'unit' contains 4 unique numbers in 5 entries. Another case is `psf7433-nlhrms psf7331-pdesmond` where the type 'psf' contains 2 unique numbers in its 2 entries. How to pull out the count of unique numbers from each type in the input? Should we use a 'if' clause or something else?

Comment: @Karthik you should consider using something like awk for that. Try: `sed -r 's/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)-.*/\1 \2/' | awk '{a[$1][$2]++}END{for (i in a) {print i,length(a[i])}}'`

Comment: to run this script for my input file all-dss-accounts.txt, i suppose i should use this `sed -r 's/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)-.*/\1 \2/' | awk '{a[$1][$2]++}END{for (i in a) {print i,length(a[i])}}' all-dss-accounts.txt`

Comment: @Karthik other way around `sed ... all-dss-accounts | awk ...`

Comment: gives me this error `awk: {a[$1][$2]++}END{for (i in a) {print i,length(a[i])}}`
`awk:       ^ syntax error`

Comment: @Karthik looks like I used a GNU awk feature. Any chance you can get GNU awk?

Comment: @muru i donno how to explain it but i'm working on a unix server using putty. i'm running my own business so i use the client's unix machine to get the input. i dont think i can use GNU.

Comment: @Karthik replace the awk expression with this: `'{a[$1,$2]++} END{for (ij in a) {split(ij,xx,SUBSEP); b[xx[1]]++;} for (i in b) {print i,b[i]}}'`

Comment: sorry for the trouble @muru but i get `./test1.sh: line 14: {a[$1,$2]++} END{for (ij in a) {split(ij,xx,SUBSEP); b[xx[1]]++;} for (i in b) {print i,b[i]}}: command not found` as the result :(

Comment: @Karthik that's an awk expression. Use it like this: `sed ... | awk '{a[$1,$2]++} END{for (ij in a) {split(ij,xx,SUBSEP); b[xx[1]]++;} for (i in b) {print i,b[i]}}'`.

Comment: it gives the result @muru but i am actually expecting an output like this [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=18742328395558995138&t=1874232839555899513873673). Here the 'count' column gives the total number of entries of the type. I want the 'unique numeric' column to show all the unique numeric values for the particular type (fap, unit, psf etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Use extended grep to and look for four digits, telling grep to only list the matches (as opposed to the whole line, which is the default):

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' <filename>
```

Sort this list of numbers and only output unique ones:

```
sort -u
```

Count the number of lines:

```
wc -l
```

Put it all together:

```
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]+' filename | sort -u | wc -l
8
```

Comment: I provided only 4 digit numerics in the sample data. My original data contains entries with 2,3 digit numeric values too. The only condition is it should not count any numeric values after the '-' character in the entry.

Comment: @Karthik - I've changed the `grep` search pattern to look for at least one digit.

Comment: My input has a few entries which contains a numeric character after the '-' character. eg: `unit7330-partners1`. In such case, it should ignore any digits after the '-' character in the entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
tr -dc '\-0-9\n' | sort -u -t- -nk1,1 | grep -c .
```

...which is, admittedly, more than a little inspired by muru's answer here. Differently, though, I use `grep` to count the lines rather than `wc` in case there are blank lines in input. His answer doesn't have a blank line problem as `grep -o` will only print lines with their match *(as `grep -c` only counts them here)*, but `tr` *does* print blank lines because the newline is one of the few characters it does not delete. This means any number of blank lines in input would skew `wc`'s results by one.

So `tr` here is more efficient probably than is `grep -o` but likely `wc` beats `grep` in the counting department. I like it this way I think for portability reasons, and also because I usually try to prune data with the most efficient filter first, and to use the less efficient ones later in the chain.

This lets `sort` pick the bits per line that it will consider in its `-u`nique sort based on its `-n`umeric sort `-k`ey which it splits on its `-t-`ab delimiter. `tr` `-d`eletes the `-c`omplement of any numeric, dash, or newline byte in its input. That way - so long as there are no `-`dashes occurring *before* the numeric strings you wish to compare, then the only thing remaining to any line is:

```
#nothing at all
```

...or...

```
[numbers]
```

...or...

```
[numbers]-[more numbers]more-dashes-...
```

So when the output is piped to `sort` we instruct it only to compare numeric strings occurring before a dash if any. In that way -dashes or not - the only numbers which matter are the ones you want to count.

So then we `grep -c`ount lines containing at least a single `.` character. The following command prints `8`:

```
tr -dc '\-0-9\n' <<\IN | sort -u -t- -nk1,1 | grep -c .
psf7433-nlhrms
unit7433-nobody
unit7333-opera
bpx7333-operations
app7333-osm
unit7330-partners
psf7331-pdesmond
unit7333-pro-09-0jm
mnp7330-redir09o-0ect
unit7333-retailbanking
cpq7333-rkarmer
unit6333-sales
ring7323-support


unit7133-telco
post7323-uadb
sun7335-ukhrms
burp7133-wfnmreply
IN
```

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), without any shell pipes (quicker) :

```
$ perl -lne '/\d+-/ and $h{$&}++;END{print scalar keys %h}' file
```

Comment: Hi, I just modified the question with a new set of input. Will the code be applicable for the new input too.

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Comment: gives me the answer 0

Comment: You have to modify `file` by your own file Karthik

Comment: works after the edit! just a doubt...will this piece of script work even if one of the file entries contains a line like sun73-ukhrms. where the numeric value is just 2 digits. Moreover, hope this script does not read any numeric value after the '-' character in the line.

Comment: New requirement satisfied chief

Comment: I need a small favor. Let me pull out 5 entries from my input. `unit7433-nobody unit7333-opera unit7333-retailbanking unit7133-telco unit6333-sales`. This type 'unit' contains 4 unique numbers in 5 entries. Another case is `psf7433-nlhrms psf7331-pdesmond` where the type 'psf' contains 2 unique numbers in its 2 entries. How to pull out the count of unique numbers from each type in the input? Should we use a 'if' clause or something else?

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution

```
awk -F'-' '{sub(/[^[:digit:]]+/, "", $1); a[$1]} END{for (k in a) ++i; print i}' file
8
```

Comment: thanks but will this script also read any numeric (just in case) which occurs after the '-' character.